# T-invariant subspaces of V.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let T be a linear operator on a vector space V over F.If W1,W2,........,Wk are T invariant subspaces of V, prove that summation i=1 to k Wi and intersection i=1 to k are T invariant subspaces of V.

Comment: What have you tried? The result is almost immediate, so where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S:= W_1+...+W_k$. We have to show that $T(S) \subseteq S.$

To this end let $w \in S$. Then there are $w_j \in W_j \quad (j=1,...,k)$ such that

$$w=w_1+...+w_k.$$

It follows that

$$T(w)=T(w_1)+...+T(w_k).$$

From $T(w_j) \in W_j \quad (j=1,...,k)$ we derive $T(w) \in S.$

The intersection is now your turn.